# next gen gallery thumbnail problem

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

Does anyone know why nextgen gallery doesn't support thumbnails with png transparency???

I'm working on this project http://decolabel.andresmijares.com/smaakvolle-etiketten/

And as you can see the slideshow work the image properly, however the thumbnails have a black background.

I'd really appreciated any kind of help :)!

Comment: Nice effect, by the way, using the transparent images over the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the site has a white background, a quick workaround could be to save the pngs as jpeg with white background?

this thread mentions a possible solution:

- wordpress dot org/support/topic/plugin-nextgen-gallery-problems-with-png-transparency-thumbnails?replies=9

this has an unpdated solution:

- wordpress dot org/support/topic/plugin-nextgen-gallery-png-thumbnails-with-transparancy-problem-1?replies=5

and this thread suggests saving as 24bit png's rather than 8bit

- wordpress dot org/support/topic/nextgen-gallery-transparent-images-showing-black-background-with-resize?replies=8#post-1921440

ps cant post all links as dont have enough rep :-(

if an admin can amend i'd be grateful

Answer (score 0):

I've seen problems .png files when they are natively resized by WordPress.  If you do not have many images you can resize the images to the thumbnail dimension then manually upload them into the gallery directory.  Useful if you only have a few thumbnails like in a designer's portfolio; not so good if it's a photographer's portfolio.